# Get data from details.json?

Tags: python, web-scraping

Objective: I have a url from which I need to get a unique id,which is available in 2 places. Specifically I need the value **3022753** highlighted in the snapshot.

My starting point is [url](https://marketsmithindia.com/mstool/eval/tcs/evaluation.jsp#/) part of StocksList.txt. Once i open the url, the information i need is available in couple of different places in link "details.json?symbol=~".

1. General --> Request URL:
2. Request Headers --> :path:

StocksList.txt

```
https://marketsmithindia.com/mstool/eval/tcs/evaluation.jsp#/
```

[image]

[image]

I tried all options for response in https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_response.asp.

Code:

```
import requests
# import pandas as pd

infile = 'C:/Volume/PythonProjects/WIP_Projects/GetJSONResponse/StocksList.txt'
outfile = 'C:/Volume/PythonProjects/WIP_Projects/GetJSONResponse/Response.txt'
timeout = 10
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

with open(infile, 'r') as IN, open(outfile, 'w') as OUT:
   for DATA in IN:
       url = DATA.strip()
       r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
       print(r.headers, file=OUT)
       # print(r.json(), file=OUT)
       # print(r.links, file=OUT)
```

Expected Output:

```
3022753
```

Comment: The information you need is not in the headers

Comment: Sorry, updated the original question. Also here is the url: https://msi-gcloud-prod.appspot.com/gateway/simple-api/ms-india/instr/0/3022753/symboldetails.json?s=20180814&e=20230814&text=TCS&lang=en&isConsolidated=1&ms-auth=3990+MarketSmithINDUID-Web0000000000+MarketSmithINDUID-Web0000000000+0+233420220828+-1412160137

Comment: What is your issue here? The question is not clear, can you explain what problem did you face?

Comment: Why do you need to get that value from a HTTP header when it's already part of the URL?

Comment: I need the unique id **3022753**  that i need to use elsewhere. This unique id is available in multiple places. In Request URL:, :path:. At the beginning, the only thing i have is https://marketsmithindia.com/mstool/eval/tcs/evaluation.jsp#/ from StocksList.

Comment: When you do a request it request the url and sends you the html. Normally inside the html there are script tags which load some javascript files, somewhere then an init is called and more resources, API requests and so on are loaded via the js. So the request you see in the development tool. If you go to `Initiator` tab for a request you can see the trace how the ajax request was triggered. No general approach how to go about it you can try to reproduce the calls, find the call that gives you the token you are looking for, use some lib which might executes the js for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID the page gets from another Ajax URL:

```py
import requests

search_url = (
    "https://msi-gcloud-prod.appspot.com/gateway/simple-api/ms-india/instr/srch.json"
)

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0"
}

params = {"text": "TCS"} # <-- your symbol here

data = requests.get(search_url, params=params, headers=headers).json()
print(data["response"]["results"][0]["instrumentId"])
```

Prints:

```
3022753
```